# How can I remove a specific HTML tag in Django templates?

Tags: python, html, django, templates, filter

I tried to use `striptags` in a Django template, but it removes all HTML tags. I just want to remove a specific HTML tag, for example `<p>` or `<h1>` tags. How can I do it in `template`?

This is my `'Post'` model: 
[POST MODEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djjHW.png)

I have a field named `text` and my view is like this:
[DRAFT VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ulsS.png)

I get and filter my Post objects/fields in `get_queryset()` method and return them to `post_draft_list.html` and then get text filed `{{post.text}}`. text contains some html tags and I want to remove them. now if I want to clean text field by `bleach`, how can I do that in my views (get_queryset)?

Comment: The documentation for `striptags` points you to [bleach](https://bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clean.html) for finer control...

Answer (score 2):

**Try:**

```
import bleach

filtered_text = bleach.clean(data_text, tags=[u'a', u'i', u'li', u'ol', u'ul'])
```

Allow only those tags what you need, in `tags`.

For more information you can follow [bleach](https://bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clean.html#stripping-markup-strip), beacuse `removetags` filter was depreciated from **django 1.8** onwards for security purpose.

Comment: I think it is depreciated now, let me see other option.

Comment: @AliasgharSoltani, Check it by first using `removetags` and then `safe` rendering.

Comment: Instead of using `removetags` use `striptags` and see if it works.

Comment: @AliasgharSoltani, I have updated my answer. Please have a look on it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok. where should I add this?

Comment: your **views.py** file

Comment: @AliasgharSoltani, First process and clean your data using bleach in views.py file and then pass to html file.

Comment: Post your viws.py file

Comment: I solved my problem with creating `templatetags` and add a filter. thanks Astik

Comment: adding the kwarg `strip=True` to what you have here was what I was looking for `bleach.clean(x, tags=[...], strip=True)`. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use [this snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/295/) however the snippet uses regular expressions to parse HTML which is NOT a good idea. So I suggest going with `bleach` as Astik mentioned too.